# Blinking cursor in BATCH file after echo command possible?

Tags: batch-file

I would like to have my cursor blinking in a specific part of my running batch.

```
@echo off

REM some code goes here ... 

setlocal
for /f %%A in ('"prompt $H & echo on & for %%B in (1) do rem"') do set "BS=%%A"
set /p Menu=%BS%  Please inform your option {1,2,3} followed by ENTER:
```

Note that the with the SET /P command the cursor symbol "_" will be blinking in front of the word "ENTER" and right next to the colon symbol ":", awaiting the user decision as in ENTER: _

However, later on in my code I have the following :

```
REM some code goes also here ...
echo:
echo Please, press any key to return to main menu
pause>nul
Call Begin
```

In this case, the cursor waits the user command but it blinks somewhere else far, rather than next to the letter "U" of the word main menu

Question - How to make the cursor blink after the "U" next to the word menu ?

Thank you in advance !

Comment: You don't have to put [SOLVED] in your title; marking an answer as accepted is sufficient.  Please check [this Meta SO post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/116101/175248) for more info.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The ECHO command issues a new line at the end of your output, so the pause blinking cursor appears on the next line.

You can use SET /P to print your prompt without a new line to get your desired results.

```
<nul set/p"=Please, press any key to return to main menu"
pause>nul
```

BTW, You probably should not be using CALL to return to the main menu. There is a limit to the number of successive CALLs that can be issued without returning. I suspect your main menu is already CALLing a routine or batch file. Your main menu should probably be in a GOTO loop, and then have each option CALL a batch or routine. Then the CALLed routine can simply EXIT /B to return to the main menu.

Comment: Thank you once more for the great contribution. Kind regards.